# WSO2 ESB AuthenticationAdmin use in JSP

Tags: jsp, maven, glassfish, wso2

I try to use the AuthenticationAdmin Proxy.
When I use the code below with a stand alone application it's working perfect.
But the problem:
I need to use this proxy in a Maven Webproject with JSP. If I copy it there it's not working and I don't know why.
I use NetBeans 7.3.1 with Glassfish 4.0.

My working application:

```
package soapclient;

import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPEnvelope;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPException;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPPart;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

/**
 *
 * @author mmuetze
 */

public class SOAPClient {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SOAPException {
        // TODO code application logic here
           try
                {
                        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:\\wso2esb\\repository\\resources\\security\\client-truststore.jks");
                        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "wso2carbon");

                        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:\\wso2esb\\repository\\resources\\security\\wso2carbon.jks");
                        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "wso2carbon");
                         // Create SOAP Connection
                        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
                        SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

                        //Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
                        String url = "https://localhost:8243/services/AuthenticationAdmin.AuthenticationAdminHttpsSoap11Endpoint";

                        SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);

                        // Process the SOAP Response
                        printSOAPResponse(soapResponse);

                        soapConnection.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                        System.err.println("Error occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
    }

    public static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception
    {
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
           SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
           SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

           // SOAP Envelope
           SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
           envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("aut", "http://authentication.services.core.carbon.wso2.org");
           SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
           SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("login", "aut");
           SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("username", "aut");
           SOAPElement soapBodyElem2 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("password", "aut");
           SOAPElement soapBodyElem3 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("remoteAddress", "aut");
           soapBodyElem1.addTextNode("admin");
           soapBodyElem2.addTextNode("admin");  
           soapBodyElem3.addTextNode("localhost");  
           soapMessage.saveChanges();

           System.out.println("Request SOAP Message = ");
           soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
           System.out.println();
           return soapMessage;
    }
    private static void printSOAPResponse(SOAPMessage soapResponse) throws Exception
        {
                TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                Source sourceContent = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent();
                System.out.println("\nResponse SOAP Message = ");
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
                transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);
        }
}
```

When I use it in my Maven WebProject I get the following:

```
INFO:   Request SOAP Message =
INFO:   <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:aut="http://authentication.services.core.carbon.wso2.org"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><aut:login><aut:username>admin</aut:username><aut:password>admin</aut:password><aut:remoteAddress>localhost</aut:remoteAddress></aut:login></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
SEVERE:   SAAJ0009: Nachricht konnte nicht gesendet werden
SEVERE:   Error occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server
SEVERE:   com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Message send failed
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:164)
    at com.tsy.datahub.ServerCheck.authentication(ServerCheck.java:104)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:77)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Message send failed
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:297)
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:160)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1886)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1341)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:515)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1090)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:252)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1323)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
    ... 54 more
```

Maybe there is a problem with glassfish?

WSO2 ESB Console says:

```
[2013-08-23 13:30:34,789] ERROR - SourceHandler I/O error: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1619)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1587)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1756)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1060)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:884)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:758)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:163)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:273)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.SSLServerIOEventDispatch.inputReady(SSLServerIOEventDispatch.java:229)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:158)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:340)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:318)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:278)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:54
2)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions indicate that there is an error during SSL certificate validation.

You need to import WSO2 Carbon certificates to GlassFish server.

Please check on how to import. This [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbyb.html) might help.

Comment: Which files do you mean? wso2carbon.jks or the client-truststore.jks?